Why does "forge tunnel" not work on Windows?
I recently installed the forge cli on my personal MacBook and my work Windows laptop (Windows 11 Enterprise).
"forge tunnel" works fine on the MacBook but not the Windows laptop.
This question refers to an older version of the forge cli and the solution is not applicable but the problem is the same. I get this:
Tunnel redirects requests you make to your local machine. This occurs for any Atlassian site where your app is installed in the specific development environment. You will not see requests from other users.
Press Ctrl+C to cancel.

Then it just hangs. I don't see this (as per the doc and running on the MacBook):
=== Running forge lint...
No issues found.

=== Bundling code...
✔ Functions bundled.

Listening for requests...

"forge deploy" and "forge install" work as normal. Any ideas?

whats your windows version?

@jamj Windows 11 Enterprise
